# How to change repository language in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I want to change the repository language to another language that is used in the repository.

[image]
[image]

Can anyone tell me how to change it?

Comment: I'm guessing responsibility -> repository, please clarify if not. Did you read [the docs](https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-languages/)?

Comment: You edited correct. I mean repository language.!

Comment: Guys, -3? Why so Harsh? (jk)

Comment: @MichalM I don't know the reason why people down voted this.!! This question is relevant to this tag thought!

Answer (score 6):

GitHub uses Linguist library to determine repository statistics. You just have to create a .gitattributes files in your repository and add the following commands:

To ignore all CSS files for examples use the `linguist-vendored` command:

```
*.html linguist-vendored
```

To ignore all files in a CSS folder for examples use this syntax:

```
css/* linguist-vendored
```

To force a certain file extension to be recognized as a javascript language for example use the `linguist-language` command:

```
*.gs linguist-language=Javascript
```

For more information check the [liguist library documentation](https://github.com/github/linguist).

Answer (score 0):

You don't. It's assigned based on the language most-used in a given repository (not sure if it's file count based or line based though).

Comment: `The percentages are calculated based on the bytes of code for each language` from https://github.com/github/linguist